# Trying to fix header-navigation bar

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar, sticky

Hey there I am trying to make my header navigation menu to stack on te top of my page ...but when I fix it, it does not appear. And instead of the navigation bars there are only puncts..no header, no nav bar....no nothin only background...
Here is my code
     HTML:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<li><a href="index.html" class="Logo"></a></li>
<li><a href="index.html"class="Home"></a></li>
<li><a href="Sugestology.html"class="Sugestology"></a></li>
<li><a href="TheCreator.html"class="Creator"></a></li>
<li><a href="InBulgaria.html"class="InBulgaria"></a></li>
<li><a href="Contacts.html"class="Contacts"></a></li>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 500;
height: 80 px;
width:100%;
}

#header li {float:left; }
#header li a.Logo {width:20%; height:80px; background:url("nav_01.jpg")}
#header li a.Home {width:20%; height:80px; background:url("nav_02.jpg")}
#header li a.Sugestology {width:20%; height:80px; background:url("nav_03.jpg")}
#header li a.Creator {width:20%; height:80px; background:url("nav_04.jpg")}
#header li a.InBulgaria {width:20%; height:80px; background:url("nav_05.jpg")}
#header li a.Contacts {width:20%; height:80px; background:url("nav_06.jpg")}
```

Once again I want this navigation to be 100% width and in the left side is the logo nav_01.jpg wich will lead to the index too....and in right the navigation bar and all this to stack on top when scroll down....but this code does not appear only six fullstops....

Comment: what folder did you put the images in? maybe the background url in css isn't right

Comment: Nope they are in the same folder as the HTML file and CSS file

Comment: Please post the complete code to JSFiddle. You have a few issues with this code such as missing UL tags and the most problematic I see, LI's are 20% width x 6 = 120%.

Comment: Your HTML is badly formed. You need to wrap the `li` in a `ul` AND contain the floats (if you haven't already done so).

Comment: So can someone show me what exactly I should do?

Comment: `a` tags don't appear beceause they are empty... so you have the choice between put some content inside tags, or set a tag in display block/inline-block with spécific height/width

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4BJLb/2/

**CSS**

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 80 px;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 500;
}
#header ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    height: 80px;
}
#header li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    width: 16.6%;
}
#header li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-size: cover; // >IE9
}

#header li a:nth-child(1) {background: url(http://placeimg.com/200/80/tech) no-repeat 0 0}
#header li a:nth-child(2) {background: url(http://placeimg.com/200/80/tech) no-repeat 0 0}
#header li a:nth-child(3) {background: url(http://placeimg.com/200/80/tech) no-repeat 0 0}
#header li a:nth-child(4) {background: url(http://placeimg.com/200/80/tech) no-repeat 0 0}
#header li a:nth-child(5) {background: url(http://placeimg.com/200/80/tech) no-repeat 0 0}
#header li a:nth-child(6) {background: url(http://placeimg.com/200/80/tech) no-repeat 0 0}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html"></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html"></a></li>
        <li><a href="Sugestology.html"></a></li>
        <li><a href="TheCreator.html"></a></li>
        <li><a href="InBulgaria.html"></a></li>
        <li><a href="Contacts.html"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you duplicate `height` in your `#header li a`

Comment: It does not appear but it's there when you click it redirects you to a page and the page places are on the right place but the backgorun does not appear

Comment: Sounds like you have the incorrect path to your background images. Try to test with the temp images I used above. If it works then you need to correct the image path.

Comment: Have you tried to make an absolute path to the images? If you use a relative path (ie. image.jpg) and then the actual page goes from index.html to dir/another-page.html then the image path will now become dir/image.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Put some text inside your divs

also, you need to to make the li `list-style: none;` to get rid off the puncts

**here is the css:**

```
#header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 500;
height: 80 px;
width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}


#header li {float:left; width:15%; height:80px; list-style: none;}
#header li a.Logo {background:url("nav_01.jpg")}
#header li a.Home {background:url("nav_02.jpg")}
#header li a.Sugestology {background:url("nav_03.jpg")}
#header li a.Creator {background:url("nav_04.jpg")}
#header li a.InBulgaria {background:url("nav_05.jpg")}
#header li a.Contacts {background:url("nav_06.jpg")}
```

*Note: You need to change the 15% to width that fits the 100% (# of divs x div's width <= 100%) other wise you will be out of the page*

**here is the html**

```
<div id="header">
<li><a href="index.html" class="Logo">1</a></li>
<li><a href="index.html"class="Home">2</a></li>
<li><a href="Sugestology.html"class="Sugestology">3</a></li>
<li><a href="TheCreator.html"class="Creator">4</a></li>
<li><a href="InBulgaria.html"class="InBulgaria">5</a></li>
<li><a href="Contacts.html"class="Contacts">6</a></li>
</div>
```

**See it in Action**

[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cY4YQ/)

Comment: This way the numbers appear and small part of the background over them but only this no full menu bars